# Query datetime as text and include different timezones

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3

**Short version:**
I have 2 users in DB, each created in a different timezone:

```
User.find(1).created_at
=> Thu, 04 Aug 2016 11:15:29 IDT +03:00
User.find(33).created_at
=> Sun, 01 Jan 2017 17:50:20 IST +02:00
```

So my table shows 11:15, and 17:50. so for example I would like to search for `17:50`, and later `11:15` as text:

```
search_param = '17:50'
```

No problem I'll just convert the date to text, then search it, But user won't be found, since the it's saved as UTC:

```
User.where("to_char(created_at,'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ilike ?", "%#{search_param}%").first
=> nil
```

To find it I'll just apply the offset to my query (adding time zone UTC+2), and indeed user was found:

```
User.where("to_char(created_at AT TIME ZONE 'UTC+2','DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ilike ?", "%#{search_param}%").first
=> User #33 @2017-01-01 17:50:20 +0200
```

BUT some users are saved as UTC+3  and some as UTC+2.. I can't apply both offsets... So if I change `search_param` to be `11:15` I won't find user_id_1 because I will also need to change `UTC+2` to `UTC+3`

- When I use UTC+2 I will only find users which were created as +2 (like `User.find(33)`).
- When I use UTC+3 I will only find users which were created as +3 (like `User.find(1)`).

My question: How to do a where query- a text search for both users' `created_at` hour, as they were both saved in a different timezone offset?

Or in this example **a query** that for a search_param `17:50` will find user_id_33 and for search_param `11:15` will find user_id_1?

---

More Details:

I notice in DB they are saved as UTC (I think):

```
User.select("created_at as created_at_db").find(33).created_at_db
=> "2017-01-01 15:50:20.903289"
User.select("created_at as created_at_db").find(1).created_at_db
=> "2016-08-04 08:15:29.171776"
```

Time setting:

```
#application.rb
    config.time_zone = 'Jerusalem'
    config.active_record.default_timezone = :utc
```

created_at column info:

```
User.columns.select{|table_col| table_col.name == 'created_at'}
=> [#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:0x81f9c48
  @coder=nil,
  @default=nil,
  @limit=nil,
  @name="created_at",
  @null=false,
  @precision=nil,
  @primary=false,
  @scale=nil,
  @sql_type="timestamp without time zone",
  @type=:datetime>]
```

Comment: Nota that `IST` and `IDT` are the same timezone (more exactly, they are complements of each other). They both "belong" to the `Asia/Jerusalem` timezone, which uses daylight saving during summer. -- If you are trying to query within that timezone, you could use something like `date_trunc('second', created_at AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Jerusalem')::time = '17:50'`

Comment: Or, if you insist using `to_char()`, then `to_char(created_at AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Jerusalem', 'HH24:MI') = '17:50'` -- There is really no need to use `LIKE` here.

Comment: @pozs doesn't work: `User.select("to_char(created_at AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Jerusalem', 'HH24:MI') as pozs").find(33).pozs` gives `=> "13:50"`.
`User.find(33).created_at` gives `Sun, 01 Jan 2017 17:50:20 IST +02:00`, instead of adding 2 hours, your solution decrease 2 hours

Comment: I see, it seems ruby does some timzone offsetting too. Could you post your table definition (at least the concrete type of `created_at` column) and the sample values as seen in the DB (not through ruby)?

Comment: **If** `created_at` is just `timestamp`, not `timestamp with time zone` (and stored in UTC), you could use `created_at AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Jerusalem'`

Comment: @pozs It worked!!, before I tried `created_at AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'IST'` and `IDT` but I didn't think to do `Asia/Jerusalem`.
If you post this as an answer I will mark it as correct- or if not I will add answer of my own and give you credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to query your user entities with:

```
date_trunc('minute', created_at AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Jerusalem')::time = '17:50'
```

Or, with `to_char()` (but less index-friendly):

```
to_char(created_at AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Jerusalem', 'HH24:MI') = '17:50'
```

The point is that `created_at` is `timestamp` (or `timestamp without time zone`, which is just an alias). First, you can tell PostgreSQL, that interpret its values as they were in UTC, with the `<timestamp> AT TIME ZONE <time zone>` operator:

```
created_at AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

Then, tell PostgreSQL to offset this value as if it were a local time in `Asia/Jerusalem` with the `<timestamp with time zone> AT TIME ZONE <time zone>` operator (which is completely different from the operator above with the same name):

```
created_at AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Jerusalem'
```

Now, you just need to truncate this value to extract only the hour & minute part.

Maybe worth mentioning that using these:

```
created_at AT TIME ZONE 'UTC+2'
created_at AT TIME ZONE 'UTC+3'
```

worked for you accidentally. These create `timestamp with time zone` values [within the `-2` and `-3` UTC](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES) offsets, respectively. Then, because your `config.active_record.default_timezone` is set to `:utc`, it is sent to your client (ruby) within the UTC time zone, which means it added `2` and `3` hours, respectively.

> Another issue to keep in mind is that in POSIX time zone names, positive offsets are used for locations west of Greenwich. Everywhere else, PostgreSQL follows the ISO-8601 convention that positive timezone offsets are east of Greenwich.